# При авторизации на gmail почту ошибка javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

Tags: java, email, gmail, javax

Была настроена проверка письма на гугл почте через АПИ. Для авторизации на почту использовались почта и пароль.
Но недавно проверка перестала проходить с вот такой ошибкой  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
Думал что что-то не так с кредами.Попробовал вручную залогиниться - всё ок
После вычитал что гугл запретило авторизацию непроверенным приложениям и скорей всего из-за  этого ошибка. Вычитал что можно включать  двухэтапную аутентификацию и потом использовать пароль для приложений.И это должно помочь.
Но,в ходе возникло пару вопросов:
1)Что нужно выбирать в названии приложения при создании пароля для приложения в гугл аккаунте
2)И что тогда должно прописываться в коде если мы убираем авторизацию через логин и пароль,а делаем через пароль
Библиотека,которая используется для входа на почту - javax.mail
Код,где идет коннект к почтовику:

```
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(
            props.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"),
            props.getProperty("mail.smpt.user"),
            props.getProperty("mail.smpt.password1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос:
1)в названии выбираешь почта, и в устройстве выбираешь с какого устр-ва будет производится вход
Но, у меня была проблема что вход выполнялся с линукс.Поэтому просто выбирал другое устройство и прописывал Linux
2)В методе connect всё так и остаётся. В пропертис там где указан mail.smpt.password1 вместо пароля,когда авторизируешся через почту+пароль, пишешь 16 значный пароль,который был сгенерирован на гугл аккаунте